# React inline functions rerender issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, composition

I have a component that uses two nested components that are based on render prop pattern. I need to combine props from both of them to be sent to the innermost function.

```
<Component1>
  {(...props1) => (
    <Component2>
      {(...props2) => <MyComponent {...props1} {...props2} />}
    </Component2>
  )}
</Component1>
```

Now, I wanted to refactor the above inline functions into class functions, so as to avoid creating new functions on every render.
First attempt:

```
render() {
  return <Component1>{this._render1}</Component1>;
}
_render1 = (...props1) => <Component2>{this._render2}</Component2>;

_render2 = (...props2) => <MyComponent {...props1} {...props2} />;
```

But now, in `render2`, I don't have access to props1, so I did:

```
render() {
  return <Component1>{this._render1}</Component1>;
}
_render1 = (...props1) => <Component2>{this._render2(...props1)}</Component2>;

_render2 = (...props1) => (...props2) => <MyComponent {...props1} {...props2} />;
```

But here, I am back again to original problem of recreating inline functions on each render (inside `_render2`).

Please suggest a way to mitigate this problem. How can I best send the combined data down? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It seems XY issue.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Component1 is a tooltip component, whereas Component2 is a React Consumer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you got a chance to take a look on React.Context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)?

You can create something like:

SomeContext.jsx

```
import React from "react";

export const SomeContext = React.createContext();
```

index.jsx

```
 <SomeContext.Provider value={this.state.contextState}>
    <div>
      ....
      <Component2 />
      <MyComponent />
      ...
    </div>
  </SomeContext.Provider>
```

Component2.jsx / MyComponent.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { SomeContext } from "./SomeContext";

export default () => (
  <SomeContext.Consumer>
      your jsx with access to the props from parent.
  </SomeContext.Consumer>
);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: how will this help me to combine the arguments to render prop from two different components? Also, let me tell you that Component2 in my case is itself a React Context Consumer.

Comment: If I understood your question, you'll have the props in your provider (parent) so, all consumers will have access to them.